# HTML/JS My "Name:" field will not submit to output form onclick=

Tags: javascript, html, css

My "sign out" Name: form will not populate/output to the "Name" column in the chart under my forms. My time, drop down boxes and sign in/sign out buttons all work but even if I change the "id" to something like "tname" it still won't populate. I'm interested in ideas for a workaround if nothing else can be done to solve this. I will list my code below. Please advise.

```html
<form name="SIGN IN" id="form1" value="1" border="5" align="center">
  <h4><br></strong>
    <table align="center" border="5">
      <tr>
        <td><label for="Name">Name:</label></tr< /td>
          <input list="Names" name="Name" id="fname">


      <tr>
        <td><input type="button" value="SIGN IN" onclick="display()" /></td>
      </tr>

      <form name="SIGN OUT" id="form2" value="1" border="5">
        <tr>
          <td>Name:<input id="fname2"> <br></td>
        </tr>
      </form>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="button" value="SIGN OUT" onclick="display()" /></td>
      </tr>



      <table width="400px" align="center" colspan="40" table border="5">
        <thead>
          <tr style="background-color:#8FBC8F;" id='header'>
            <td align="center"><b>Name</b></td>
            <td align="center"><b>Company</b></td>
            <td align="center" class="wide"><b>Time In</b></td>
            <td align="center" class="wide"><b>Time Out</b></td>
            <td align="center" class="wide"><b>Description of Work</b></td>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <template id="row">
            <tr style="background-color:#8F8FBC;" class="data">
              <td align="center">
                <div class="displayarea"></div>
              </td>
              <td align="center">
                <div class="displayarea1"></div>
              </td>
              <td align="center">
                <div class="displayarea2"></div>
              </td>
              <td align="center">
                <div class="displayarea3"></div>
              </td>
              <td align="center">
                <div class="displayarea4"></div>
              </td>

            </tr>
          </template>

        </tbody>
      </table>
```

```js
function alternateGetValue() {
  const Items = [...document.querySelectorAll('.data')]
  .map(row => [...row.querySelectorAll('td>div')]
       .map(d => d.textContent).join(',')
      ).join('\n');
  console.log(Items);
  return Items;
}

function display() {
  const template = document.getElementById("row");
  const clone = template.content.cloneNode(true);
  const additem = (dest, src) => {
    const s = document.querySelector(src);
    clone.querySelector(dest).innerHTML = s.value;
    s.value = "";
  };
  additem(".displayarea", "#fname");
  additem(".displayarea1", "#lname");
  additem(".displayarea2", "#sname");
  additem(".displayarea3", "#pname");
  additem(".displayarea4", "#jname");

  template.insertAdjacentElement('beforebegin', clone.firstElementChild);
}

function destroyClickedElement(event) {
  document.body.removeChild(event.target);
}
```

[image: Current GUI]

Comment: @Amith, Thank you for helping me with edits.

Comment: Considering the code provided, you are calling `display()` on both SIGN IN and SIGN OUT. In `display()`, you are supposed to get value from `#fname2` in case of SIGN OUT.

Comment: And kindly edit your code for clarity. There are tags left unclosed or wrongly closed.

Comment: Thank you @Sana Mumtaz. Should I be using an alternate call method for "Sign Out"? I apologize for the tags but I'm still a beginner and I'm not sure which of my tags are unclosed or wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the code provided, you need to get value from input with id `#fname2` in case of SIGN OUT. You can either call separate functions on SIGN IN and SIGN OUT, or you can pass a value to `display()` function, based on which you can determine which input id to get value from. Below is the implementation of the second approach.

```js
function alternateGetValue() {
  const Items = [...document.querySelectorAll('.data')]
    .map(row => [...row.querySelectorAll('td>div')]
      .map(d => d.textContent).join(',')
    ).join('\n');
  console.log(Items);
  return Items;
}

function display(isSignOut) {
  const template = document.getElementById("row");
  const clone = template.content.cloneNode(true);
  const additem = (dest, src) => {
    const s = document.querySelector(src);
    clone.querySelector(dest).innerHTML = s.value;
    s.value = "";
  };
  additem(".displayarea", isSignOut ? "#fname2" : "#fname");

  template.insertAdjacentElement('beforebegin', clone.firstElementChild);
}

function destroyClickedElement(event) {
  document.body.removeChild(event.target);
}
```

```html
<table align="center" border="5">
  <form name="SIGN IN" id="form1" value="1" border="5" align="center">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label for="Name">Name:</label>
        <input list="Names" name="Name" id="fname">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="center">
        <input type="button" value="SIGN IN" onclick="display(false)" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </form>
  <form name="SIGN OUT" id="form2" value="1" border="5" align="center">
    <tr>
      <td>Name:<input id="fname2"> <br></td>
    </tr>
  </form>
  <tr>
    <td align="center">
      <input type="button" value="SIGN OUT" onclick="display(true)" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table width="400px" align="center" colspan="40" table border="5">
  <thead>
    <tr style="background-color:#8FBC8F;" id='header'>
      <td align="center"><b>Name</b></td>
      <td align="center"><b>Company</b></td>
      <td align="center" class="wide"><b>Time In</b></td>
      <td align="center" class="wide"><b>Time Out</b></td>
      <td align="center" class="wide"><b>Description of Work</b></td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <template id="row">
      <tr style="background-color:#8F8FBC;" class="data">
        <td align="center">
          <div class="displayarea"></div>
        </td>
        <td align="center">
          <div class="displayarea1"></div>
        </td>
        <td align="center">
          <div class="displayarea2"></div>
        </td>
        <td align="center">
          <div class="displayarea3"></div>
        </td>
        <td align="center">
          <div class="displayarea4"></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
     </template>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you @SanaMumtaz! I used the call display true/false and the form is working. I didn't know how to manipulate the display function and you have shown me a great method for doing that. :)